# How to toggle button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to push a data in array when button pressed and delete it from array when button pressed one more time (and change the button class).

```
<button 
    *ngFor="#color of colors"
      [class.selected]="color === selectedColors"
      (click)="onPress(color)">
      {{color.name}}
</button>
```

I put a two methods in my class - onPress & hasColor

```
onPress(color: Color) {
this.selectedColors = color;
  // ckecking color in array
 if (this.hasColor(this.colorsArray,this.selectedColors.id)) {  
        //need to splice a color from array and change background color to default (to blue color)    
 } else {       
    // if not in colorsArray then push and change class to .selected
   this.colorsArray.push(this.selectedColors.id);
                         }
            } 

 hasColor(arrayC,id) {
      arrayC.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === id) {
          return true;
        }
          return false;            
      });
    }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OaXIWplN8J0BoTrs5PL8?p=preview)

How can i do it?  hasColor method returns true or false but in never returns in onPress method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> hasColor method returns true or false

No, it doesn't.

The anonymous function you pass to `forEach` returns `true` or `false` (and does so for every item in the loop).

The `hasColor` function doesn't have a return statement of its own at all.

If you want to see if *any* item matches in your for loop, then you need to use a variable to track to see if you have any matches, and then to return that variable after the loop ends.

```
hasColor(arrayC, id) {
    var match = false;
    arrayC.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item === id) {
            match = true;
        }
    });
    return match;
}
```